# Get the test results' folder in script from TFS 2015 build

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

The team are using the TFS 2015 vNext build system to manage our CI build. We want to use some script to parse the test results. But the test results folder always named by a GUID which is assigned automatically for each build. For example:

[image]

Is there any way to get which specific folder or multiple folders are used to store the test results just for current build run during the build running, for example by using some variables?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Agent Common Variable ：

> **Variable Name:** *Common.TestResultsDirectory*
>
> **Environment Variable Name:** *COMMON_TESTRESULTSDIRECTORY*
>
> **Description:** The local path on the agent where the test results are created. Will be $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\TestResults
>
> Source: [Use variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/variables)

Note: you may need  to use corresponding generated environment variables (for example $env:COMMON_TESTRESULTSDIRECTORY) in powershell script.

```
$FolderLocation = $env:COMMON_TESTRESULTSDIRECTORY
```

Comment: The COMMON_TESTRESULTSDIRECTORY can not get the random id under the TestResults folder. How can I change the random GUID into my build number?

Comment: There is no this build-in feature . However, you can try to write your own extensions to achieve it. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview